# what does the dash here mean?

Tags: em-dash

Considering https://www.grammarly.com/blog/dash/, to convey the same literal meaning, I think a dash can be replaced with a comma, a colon, or a blank, but in the below, "stage three pancreatic cancer" is a diagnosis and is not in apposition to "a grim prognosis," so the dash cannot be replaced with one of the three. Rather, I guess the reporter wants to mean she faced a grim prognosis due to stage three pancreatic cancer. In this case, what role does the dash play? It comes at 07:00 in the NBC News in [this video](https://archive.org/download/KNTV_20220602_013000_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt/KNTV_20220602_013000_NBC_Nightly_News_With_Lester_Holt.mp4?t=1268/1328&exact=1&ignore=x.mp4):

> Now to that breakthrough treatment announced today in the New England
> Journal of Medicine for pancreatic cancer and the possibility it will
> help patients with other types of cancer as well. Here is NBC's Blayne
> Alexander.
>
> In early 2018, Kathy Wilks faced **a grim prognosis -- stage three
> pancreatic cancer**. She didn't know how long she had to live. Her
> treatment was grueling -- eight rounds of chemotherapy, surgery,
> radiation. “It was a lot of nausea, very tired, a lot of just… not
> wanting to get out of bed.”

Comment: I think the writer is using _prognosis_ loosely to mean the same as _diagnosis_.

Comment: But **stage three pancreatic cancer** IS "in apposition" to **a grim prognosis,** since both those highlighted elements refer to the same thing (either could be discarded, and the sentence would still make sense). It's pointless nit-picking to claim that the disease and the prognosis are "different" things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in commments, appositives don't have to be strict equivalents. That's often how they're taught to English-language learners, but that's often not how they're used in practice. Even if the author wrote "diagnosis" (which is probably what was intended, as you suggest), the two would not be strictly equivalent; after all, a doctor gives a diagnosis but does not give cancer (hopefully). Nevertheless, this "loose equivalence" is very common in English, and the intended meaning is widely understood by listeners and readers. We can therefore assume that the author meant "stage three pancreatic cancer" as an appositive.